# This asp.net code is not working

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

Anyone know why the following is not working?

```
Dim strPhrase As String = "'%office%'"

objStringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

objSQLConnection = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connString"))

objSQLCommand = New SqlCommand("select col1, col2 from table1 where phrase like @phrase", objSQLConnection)

objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@phrase", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = strPhrase

objSQLCommand.Connection.Open()
objSQLDataReader = objSQLCommand.ExecuteReader()

While objSQLDataReader.Read()
objStringBuilder.Append(objSQLDataReader("col1") & " - " & objSQLDataReader("col2"))
End While

objSQLDataReader.Close()
objSQLCommand.Connection.Close()

return objStringBuilder.tostring()
```

If I remove anything to do with `phrase`, it starts working again, i.e:

```
objStringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

objSQLConnection = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connString"))

objSQLCommand = New SqlCommand("select col1, col2 from table1", objSQLConnection)

objSQLCommand.Connection.Open()
objSQLDataReader = objSQLCommand.ExecuteReader()

While objSQLDataReader.Read()
objStringBuilder.Append(objSQLDataReader("col1") & " - " & objSQLDataReader("col2"))
End While

objSQLDataReader.Close()
objSQLCommand.Connection.Close()

return objStringBuilder.tostring()
```

I get no errors, it just returns a blank string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the '' from around your search phrase, the command object deals with all that for you.  i.e.

```
Dim strPhrase As String = "%office%"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make it like this

```
Dim strPhrase As String = "%office%"
```

and add bellow line to the end of your connection string

```
allow user variables=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

make it like this

```
Dim strPhrase As String = "%office%"
```

Comment: oops its vb.net so you dont need the ;

Comment: Is it? no idea about VB.NET :). Good To know though